# Does anybody know this paperfolding curve?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, fractals

In experiments with paperfolding curves, I've constructed an interesting example I cannot find anywhere else.

[image: Few initial generations]

It is constructed like the “terdragon", where every time the strip is folded to the shape of "Z", but before each step we flip the strip to the other side. (Doing so with the classical dragon curve construction leads to a triangle-filling curve.) Like for the terdgaron, the curve approximations are drawn on a triangular grid with 60 degree angles.

Has anybody seen this before and can anybody provide a reference? I'm going to include this example in a popular text and would like to know the name of the object or its original discoverer.

A similar fractal is shown in plate 7 but not discussed in G. Edgar "[Measure, topology and fractal geometry](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-74749-1)".